Failed to load effect file: /core/corecommon.fx (6,34): error X3004: undeclared identifier FIXED_WIDTH
type here

Hi, I'm trying to make a custom .fx file for an application called MikuMikuDance, after editing the file, when loading it, an error message from another file appeared
heres the beginning of the code:
\*
Dippen
作成: サンフラワーふじ
\*/
#if FIXED
float2 ViewportSize = float2(FIXED_WIDTH, FIXED_HEIGHT);
#else
float2 ViewportSize : VIEWPORTPIXELSIZE;
#endif

I tried to make a custom effect file with the code of this website
https://nekofac.com/archives/1172#toc2

the image in the website has a very cool outline which is what the website was teaching.
I would change the code if could, but I basically don't know what to do
